# Cancel URL not showing on paypal

Tags: paypal

This is my form

```
    <form action="https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="@param">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="IN">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="MyItem">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="100.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancelUrl" value="http://localhost:9000">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_paynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">

    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
```

What should i also add here so that i can get cancel and back to the buyesr's site option?
[image: See image]

**Q2**-  How i will add direct credit card payment rather create paypal account ? please help

i want to show like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You've misspelt it. It is 'cancel_url'.

Comment: and, and what will be the solution for second query ???? how i'll be able to show credit card payment rather creating an account on paypal ??

Comment: And if i changed with cancel_url, it still not showing return/ cancel url on my page :(

Answer (score 0):

on the checkout page, look for the 'cancel_return' hidden form element:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" id="cancel_return" value="" />
```

set the value of the cancel_return form element to the URL you wish to return to:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" id="cancel_return" value="http://royaltytech.in" />
```

[image]